# Error while opening XML in IE8

Tags: xml, internet-explorer-8

Issue:

By using Pega PRPC Standard functions, i have generated XML that contains complete case data. but while opening this XML in **IE8**, due to some special characters in the XML, IE8 is throwing "**An invalid character was found in text content**" error.

To debug this error, I have opened the XML in notepad++. After changing the Encoding to **UTF-8,** i can see **xA0** as the special character which is causing this issue. I can also notice similar issue with symbols like copyright, quotes etc. Sometimes the same XML is opening in Chrome without any issue.

As mentioned in other forums and threads, I tried incorporating the xml encoding and version using meta tags, but there is no difference. Is there a handle all the special characters without this error in IE8?